# Finding the range of a rational function.

Tags: calculus

Let $$y= \frac x{x^2 + 1}$$

So, $yx^2 - x + y = 0$
or $$x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$$

Now since x is real, $(1-4y^2) \geq 0$.
So, we get range $[-1/2,1/2]$

I am a bit confused here. Since x is real, the solutions of x should not have denominator  $0$ which means $y$ can't be $0$ ( since the solutions of $x$ we get by quadratic formula have denominator $2y$).

Then why do we include $0$ in range?

Comment: Does real domain exclude $0?$

Comment: No, domain is the set of all reals.

Comment: $y$ is zero when $x$ is zero.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, it is easy to see that  0 is in range, but if we look at the solutions of x, ( by quadratic formula), it has denominator 0 when y is 0 and since x is real, denominator should be non zero. Maybe, i am missing something very basic.

Comment: You're missing the numerator, which is also zero.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the $\frac00$ form in $$x = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$$
So this becomes $$\underset{y\to 0}{\lim}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y} = 0$$
What's actually going on is, we have $y=\frac x{1+x^2}$[image]

and also by your approach
 $$x = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-4y^2}}{2y}$$
where the $'+'$ sign results in $x \in (-\infty,-1]\cup [+1,+\infty)$ part of graph because $y\in [-\frac12,+\frac12]-\{0\}$
$$y=\frac12,x=1$$
$$y=-\frac12,x=-1$$
$$y\to 0^+,x\to +\infty$$
$$y\to 0^-,x\to -\infty$$
 and the $'-'$ sign results in $x \in [-1,+1]$ part of graph because $y \in [-\frac12,+\frac12]$. ($0$ being included because of the limit)
$$y=\frac12,x=1$$
$$y=-\frac12,x=-1$$
$$y=0,x=0$$

Comment: What i got is , when we take '+' sign in quadratic formula, we will exclude 0 because x is real. But taking '-' sign results in indeterminate form, in that case we find limit of solution at 0, if limit is in domain, then we include 0 in range. So, the range is union of both solutions we get from + and - sign. Is this okay?

Comment: You didn't get the full thing! Read it again.

Answer (score 0):

You may also proceed in the following way:

- $f$ is defined everywhere and obviously $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$.
- $f$ is odd: $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

So, it is enough to find the maximum on $[0, \infty)$ which can be easily found using AM-GM:

- $a + b \geq 2\sqrt{ab}$ for $a,b \geq 0$ and equality holds iff $a=b$
  $$\stackrel{x\geq 0}{\Longrightarrow} y= \frac x{x^2 + 1} \stackrel {AM-GM}{\leq} \frac{x}{2\sqrt{x^2\cdot 1}} = \frac{1}{2}$$
  The maximum of $y = \frac{1}{2}$ is attained for $x= 1$. So, the minimum is $-\frac{1}{2}$ attained at $x= -1$. All together
  $$\operatorname{Range}(f) = \left[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right]$$

Comment: Clearly an uninformed down vote. :-)